# Dismiss UIViewController of Popover style from within itself

Tags: uiviewcontroller, popover, dismiss

I have two UIViewControllers in Storyboard, from the main one I press a button to show the second one using a segue of a Popover style, in the second one I have one button (Cancel), I would to dismiss the second UIViewController (Popover) when I click Cancel.

I have read many different answers for similar questions, none of them addressed my specific requirements

Thanks

Comment: Found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966677/storyboard-dismissing-popover-using-delegate-protocol-method