# Dismiss a popover from itself programatically

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, popover

I'm making a UIPopoverController and displaying it. All is well, content is loading... except I need to dismiss the popover when a button is pressed. The UIPopoverController's delegate is set to `self` but I don't know how to call a method in the parent view controller.

Comment: [google](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=How+to+dismiss+UIPopoverController&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIPopoverController` has method 
    - (void)dismissPopoverAnimated:(BOOL)animated

so you can dismiss it directly from itself.

Unless you meant that you want to dismiss popover from its `contentViewController`, then there is at least dozen of answers regarding that here - for instance similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922254/how-to-dismiss-uipopover-from-a-button-in-the-popover)

Comment: I need to dismiss the popover from the `contentViewController`.

Comment: The answer you linked to is out-of-date