# Dismissing UIPopover

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, dismiss

I have a popover displayed from a barButton, I just want that when I tap a button in the popover the popover is dismissed.

I tried a this way and adding a public method in the viewController that creates the popover to dismiss it, but nothing happens.

Any idea?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5922254/1429262

Answer (score 0):

You can Using `dismissPopoverAnimated` Method of PopoverController you can dismiss popover.

try this,

```
 - (IBAction) buttonClick:(id)sender
{
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: I've already tried this, but nothing happens...